# Numpy filter pixel indices

Tags: python, image, numpy, pixel

I want to extract the <s>sum</s> count of all pixels of an RGB image where R=0 and B=0 and where the x,y coordinates of those pixels are lying on the border of an image.

First I get the coordinates of the pixels with R=0 and B=0:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
i = cv2.imread("test2.png")
indices = np.where((i[:, :, 0] == 0) & (i[:, :, 2] == 0))
```

Which gives me a list of the coordinates. Now I want to get the sum of all pixels where the x position is 0 or the image width (in this case 21).

I could sort the list but I would like to stick to numpy arrays if possible. Is there an fancy way to do it?

[image]

Comment: By `sum of all pixels`, do you mean count of all pixels?

Comment: Yes the count, I will update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach #1**

With `X` along the second axis, here's one *fancy* way -

```
(i[...,[0,2]]==0).all(-1)[:,[0,-1]].sum()
```

**Approach #2**

With multi-dim indexing -

```
(i[:,[0,-1],[0,2]]==0).sum()
```

**Approach #3**

For performance, use more of `slicing` -

```
mask = (i[...,0]==0) & (i[...,2]==0)
out_x = (mask[:,0] + mask[:,-1]).sum()
```

On older NumPy versions, `np.count_nonzero` might be better than `.sum()`.

Comment: Yes I mean counting. print ((i[:, :, 0] == 0) & (i[:, :, 2] == 0)).all(-1)[[0,-1]].sum() return 0 but it should be 1 for the test image.

Comment: print ((i[:, :, 0] == 0) & (i[:, :, 2] == 0)).all(-1)[:,[0,-1]].sum() gives IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: @snowflake If you have to use that format, skip `.all()` , like so - `((i[...,0]==0) & (i[...,2]==0))[:,[0,-1]].sum()`. Or follow the proposed two approaches.